# Json decode Undefined index while inserting

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, symfony

```
json


  {
      "data": {
        "acct": [
          {
            "maxaddons": "1",
            "ip": "192.168.0.20",
            "ipv6": ["0101:ca75:0101:ca75:0101:ca75:0101:ca77"],
            "outgoing_mail_suspended": 0,
            "outgoing_mail_hold": 0,
            "min_defer_fail_to_trigger_protection": 5,
            "legacy_backup": 0,
            "diskused": "0M",
            "maxftp": "2",
            "startdate": "13 Jul 08 14:33",
            "max_defer_fail_percentage": "10",
            "disklimit": "100M",
            "is_locked": "0",
            "suspendtime": null,
            "email": "",
            "domain": "example.com",
            "unix_startdate": 1373312011,
            "user": "example",
            "plan": "plan9",
            "shell": "\/bin\/bash",
            "maxpop": "20",
            "backup": 0,
            "theme": "paper_lantern",
            "owner": "root",
            "max_email_per_hour": "100",
            "suspendreason": "not suspended",
            "maxlst": "5",
            "suspended": 0,
            "maxsql": "1",
            "maxparked": "1",
            "partition": "home",
            "maxsub": "5"
          },
        ]
      },
      "metadata": {
        "version": 1,
        "reason": "OK",
        "result": 1,
        "command": "listaccts"
      }
    }
```

//controller

```
public function ApiAction()
      {
          $Cpanel = new \Gufy\CpanelPhp\Cpanel;
          $Cpanel->setAuthType('hash');
          $Cpanel->setHost($this->container->getParameter('api_host'));
          $Cpanel->setAuthorization($this->container->getParameter('api_user'), $this->container->getParameter('api_hash'));
          $Cpanel->setTimeout(50);

          $Arguments = array();
          $QueryCpanel= $Cpanel->__call('listaccts', $Arguments);
          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
          $json = json_decode($QueryCpanel, true);

          foreach ($json as $List) {
            $Data['Domain'] =$List ['domain'];
            $Data['IP'] = $List ['ip'];
            $Data['UserName'] = $List ['user'];
            $Data['Email'] = $List ['email'];
            $Data['StartDate'] = $List ['startdate'];
            $Data['DiskPartition'] = $List ['partition'];
            $Data['Quota'] = $List ['disklimit'];
            $Data['DiskSpaceUsed'] = $List ['diskused'];
            $Data['Package'] = $List ['plan'];
            $Data['Theme'] = $List ['theme'];
            $Data['Owner'] = $List ['owner'];
            $Data['UnixStartDate'] = $List ['unix_startdate'];

              $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Listaccts')
                  ->InsertListaccts('listaccts', $Data);
        }
```

Iam trying to insert data from api to database and I keep getting error
Notice: Undefined index: domain

If refresh my browser then I get this error

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO  (Domain, IP, UserName, Email, StartDate, DiskPartition, Quota, DiskSpaceUsed, Package, Theme, Owner, UnixStartDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]:

I also tried with controller persist I got same error there.
I dont know what iam doing wrong.

Comment: var_dump($List) in your foreach. And do var_dump($Data) after you set all the values. Does it contain the values that you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure of the JSON string from the API is as shown above, then apparently the access method is somewhat incorrect.

The correct method should be as follows:

```
$json = json_decode($QueryCpanel, true);
foreach($json["data"]["acct"] as $list){
    echo "Domain: ".$list["domain"];
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IEVUY57643)

An assumption here is that in case of API returning multiple accounts, they will all be supplied as arrays under the `data` index.

Although it might be unlikely, but if at all your array structure repeats within `data` directly, then the `foreach` and subsequent referencing would need a little bit of change. Maybe something on the lines of:

```
foreach($json["data"] as $list){
    ....
}
```

In any case, if you use `print_r(json);`, you'd be able to get an idea on the access route to take to get to any index.

Hope this helps. Do let me know if I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: thanks, at the moment iam getting another error iam trying this way: foreach ($json ['acct']as $listaccts) {
            $Data['Domain'] =$listaccts ['domain'];  it is giving me: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO <listaccts> (Domain, IP, UserName, Email, StartDate, DiskPartition, Quota, DiskSpaceUsed, Package, Theme, Owner, UnixStartDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params[,,,], params are correct. when I use $var = new Listaccts();
              $var->setDomain($listaccts['domain']); and then persist it work but. i need to do it in another way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't understood everything in the comment above. I thought trying to access `$json['acct']` shouldn't ideally work, since `acct` index is defined under `data` in the first place, which doesn't seem to be considered in the `foreach` loop. I do acknowledge you saying _params are correct_ and therefore trust that you've somehow got them as expected. However, I don't fully get the reference to _another way_. If you can `echo` the variables and see that they're correct, suggest you use those directly in the prepared query instead of trying to store them in intermediary variables.

Comment: To clarify further, if you debug with `echo $listaccts ['domain'];` and see the output correctly, would it not help if you used `$listaccts['domain']`, `$listaccts['ip']`, etc. directly in the query? Going by the exception message, is it a fair assumption to make that you have PDO Prepared Queries implemented in your code somewhere?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did print_r(json); and my array was acct, it works now.